# When you save favorites in Media Player Classic where are they saved

Tags: windows-7, media-player-classic

I would like to transfer all my favorites from another computer but I am not sure where they are.

Answer (score 4):

In case of a portable install (**Store settings to .ini file** option selected under Settings), the list can be found under a section called, not surprisingly, **[Favorites]**, in the MPlayerC.ini file.

In case of a normal install look under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Gabest\Media Player Classic\Favorites` in the registry.

Comment: My case goes one step further, it is a normal install (no ini). However, the hard drive where the system is is only accessible externally, that is, I cannot boot into it but i can access its data. How can I find the registry key?

Comment: You can [load registry hive files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx) (see locations [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/where-are-the-windows-registry-files-located-in-windows-7)) in regedit or 3rd party registry editor, access the key and export the data.

Answer (score 4):

In Media Player Classic 1.7+ version (**installed** version, not <del>portable</del>) I found favorites under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MPC-HC\MPC-HC\Favorites\Files`